# How is match implemented in a language like Rust?

Tags: compiler-construction, language-design

I'm not a functional programmer. So I'm not very familiar with pattern matching, patterns, or any of that stuff. To me I only understand the concept of the good old `switch` statement.

How would a compiler implement a match statement? What exactly is the difference between match and a switch? There's a GNU C99 extension that allows you to have ranges in cases of a switch, is there a difference between:

```
match x {
    0 ... 9 => ...,
    _ => ...,
}
```

and

```
switch (x) {
case 0 ... 9: ...; break;
default: ...; break;
}
```

Note that the second snippet is a simple C switch with this GNU extension.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A pattern match on constant values can be implemented as a jump table or a sequence of conditional jumps - just like switch statements. Allowing ranges does not change this situation much.

Rust enums (at least the ones with members) are implemented like tagged unions, i.e. structs that contain a tag and a union of structs that contain the members.

A pattern match on an enum is then simply translated as a switch on its tag (and also binding the variables bound by the pattern to the members of the union). So something like this Rust code:

```
enum Result {
  SingleResult(i32),
  TwoResults(i32, i32),
  Error
}

match someResult {
  Result::SingleResult(res) => f(res),
  Result::TwoResults(res1, res2) => g(res1, res2),
  Result::Error => error()
}
```

would translate to the same machine code (presumably) as the following C code:

```
struct Result {
  enum {
    SingleResult, TwoResults, Error
  } tag;
  union {
    struct {
      int arg1;
    } singleResult;
    struct {
      int arg1;
      int arg2;
    } twoResults;
  } value;
};

switch(someResult.tag) {
  case SingleResult: {
    int res = someResult.value.singleResult.arg1;
    f(res);
    break;
  }
  case TwoResults: {
    int res1 = someResult.value.twoResults.arg1;
    int res2 = someResult.value.twoResults.arg2;
    g(res1, res2);
    break;
  }
  case Error: {
    error();
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Comment: do you have any references or relevant source code to back this up?

Comment: @TylerDavis No, but I did look at the generated code to verify.